# Should beans for making flour be soaked?

Tags: flour, beans

I am considering trying to make my own bean flour from black/pinto/red beans, for use in pasta. I cannot find any references to soaking first, all recipes just says to grind them into flour. Except for one I found using chickpeas.
Is soaking not necessary, or is it maybe just taken for granted?

Comment: if they were wet, you'd end up with a paste.  You want dry things to turn into flour

Comment: Yes, naturally it would have to be dried afterwards. Beans could be dried whole, or made into a paste and then ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.thehealthyhomeeconomist.com/gram-chickpea-flour/

the answer is yes according to this article cat

Comment: Thanks. It does however also say that if you only use it occasionally, you can use raw chickpeas, though it is not as nutritional as soaked or sprouted.